# Create Table As Select and add an Index SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a view that I'd like to create a table from in a query. I'd also like to add a primary key to the table, I was thinking something like the following:

```
SELECT *
, PK INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY

INSERT INTO TESTTABLE

FROM my_view

SELECT * FROM TESTTABLE

DROP TESTTABLE
```

The above does not work, so...

a) is it possible and b) if so, how?

Thank you,

Comment: why don't you add the primary key column to the `view` itself and call it when needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SELECT INTO` to create new table and `ALTER` it to add PK:

```
SELECT *
INTO TESTTABLE
FROM my_view;

ALTER TABLE TESTTABLE
ADD PK INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY;

SELECT *
FROM TESTTABLE;

DROP TABLE TESTTABLE;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3f394/1/0)**</kbd>

Comment: When I check the syntax on this one I get the error of `Unknown object 'TESTTABLE' used in CREATE, DROP or ALTER statement` it seems to be only the `DROP` that is causing this problem as when I check syntax without it, its fine. Any thoughts?

Comment: @MCP_infiltrator Try with schema part `dbo.TESTTABLE`

Comment: negative...maybe I do not have DROP table permissions?

Comment: @MCP_infiltrator Check new demo, do you call it in stored procedure?

Comment: I do not use any sp, I wrote the view and it works well, I just want to create a table to add an index too, I will probably want to create an sp that will update the table every two weeks.

Comment: Do you do exactly the same steps? 1)SELECT INTO ... 2) ALTER 3) SELECT?

Comment: Yes I do `SELECT *
INTO smsdss.TESTTABLE
FROM SMSDSS.C_sOFTMENT_DENIALS_DETAILS_V;

ALTER TABLE smsdss.TESTTABLE
ADD PK INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY;

SELECT * FROM smsdss.TESTTABLE;

DROP smsdss.TESTTABLE;`

Comment: @MCP_infiltrator **`DROP TABLE smsdss.TESTTABLE;`** You need to specify what are you dropping :)